# Xamarin forms not sending Authorization header

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, xamarin.forms

I know this question might seem like a duplicate, but I have tried every solution I saw before asking this question again.

I'm trying to consume a REST API which I wrote myself with Django Rest Framework, using C# HttpClient in Xamarin Forms. The request is being sent but it does not include the required **Authorization** with **Token** as scheme.

Here are the things I've tried:

```
public async Task<IssueListModelView> FetchIssues(string token, string type)
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(XTMonitorContants.SERVICE_BASE_URL);
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(XTMonitorContants.SERVICE_ISSUES_URL + type.ToLower()));

    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);

    //client.
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", token); 
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token " + token);
    var response = client.SendAsync(request);
    var jsonString = response.ContinueWith(t => { return t.Result; }).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    IssueListModelView resp = new IssueListModelView();
    if (jsonString != "")
    {
        try
        {
            resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IssueListModelView>(jsonString);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            resp.error = "Internal Server Error";
        }

    }
    return resp;
}
```

I have also tried to send the request directly without using **HttpRequestMessage**, but also gave me the same server response of

> "Authentication credentials were not provided."

**Request made by Postman**

> GET /api/issues/all HTTP/1.1
>
> Host: example.com
>
> Authorization: Token ffba1c43ac346945b788768e2a428d5e5d3c1fc9
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Postman-Token: 0c1eb96d-d9d6-a9e7-0cfa-0444fdc0248e

**Request made by HttpClient**

```
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://example.com/api/issues/all', Version: 1.1, Content: <null>, Headers: { Authorization: Token ffba1c43ac346945b788768e2a428d5e5d3c1fc9 }}
```

Please note that I've tested the API properly using Postman and also setup Swagger, it works fine on both.

Would be glad if someone could give me a hand here, as I think there's probably something I'm missing out

Comment: Try using a plain HttpWebRequest, HttpClient has many bugs.

Comment: @Gusman thanks, I'd check it out as I've not used it before now.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to mix blocking (`.Result`) and async code. Make the method async all the way.

Also when setting the request Authorization header try using the `Authorization` property on the headers

```
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(tokenType, token);
```

Refactored method

```
public async Task<IssueListModelView> FetchIssues(string token, string type) {
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(XTMonitorContants.SERVICE_BASE_URL);
    var uri = new Uri(XTMonitorContants.SERVICE_ISSUES_URL + type.ToLower());
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", token);

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    IssueListModelView resp = new IssueListModelView();
    if (jsonString != "") {
        try {
            resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IssueListModelView>(jsonString);
        } catch (Exception) {
            resp.error = "Internal Server Error";
        }
    }
    return resp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I've tried this earlier, but would give it a try again hopefully it would work this time around

Comment: I just tried your suggestions, and I still get the same **401** response code

Comment: @phourxx inspect the raw requests sent when using the code and postman. Compare then Too see what differences exist that may be causing the issue.

Comment: I have edited my question to include each request preview

Comment: @phourxx could be the `https` causing the issue. Have seen a few questions with this problem. See if you are able to set `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`

Comment: I have disabled ssl certificate check in `OnCreate` and `FinishedLaunching` functions in my Droid and iOS standalones respectively by adding `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after thorough checks, I found out that I was missing a trailing slash in my url, the server was redirecting my request from **example.com/api/issues/all** to **example.com/api/issues/all/** so it wasn't maintaining the header while redirecting.

Finally, for other people that might run into same problem, or could be trying to consume API, you might want to checkout [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/), I was able to make the whole request thing and deserialize the json directly to C# object with a single line, cool right?

Thanks for your responses @Nkosi