# Post request to api works for Android but not for IOS. Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've been trying to create a function that validates my token and it works for Android but not for IOS. The response on IOS from my custom API returns 401 unauthorized (which it should when you send an invalid key), but I've tried the key in postman and it's valid.

Maybe this has something to do with formatting? But I don't see what would be the difference between Android and IOS.

Some code:

```
public async Task<T> PostResponse<T>(string weburl, string jsonstring) where T : class
    {
        var Token = App.TokenDatabase.GetToken();
        string ContentType = "application/json";
        var token = string.Format("Token token={0}", Token.access_token);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        try
        {
            var result = await client.PostAsync(weburl, new StringContent(jsonstring, Encoding.UTF8, ContentType));
            if(result.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                var JsonResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                try
                {
                    var ContentResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonResult);
                    return ContentResp;
                }
                catch { return null; }

            }

        }
        catch { return null;  }
        return null;
    }
```

I've created some logs on the server side and when I run the IOS app the token doesn't get passed on to the server for some reason.

PHP code:

```
$token = null;
$headers = apache_request_headers();
if(isset($headers['Authorization'])){
  $matches = array();
  preg_match('/Token token=(.*)/', $headers['Authorization'], $matches);
  if(isset($matches[1])){
    $token = $matches[1];
  }
} 

file_put_contents('../config/log.txt', $token);
```

I've checked that the app sends the token. It disappears somewhere on the way.

EDIT: After some logging, I found out that the token is in the header but not in the Authorization header when sent through IOS, how do you solve this?

Comment: if you control the server, you need to compare the requests from Android and iOS to determine what the difference is

Comment: Are you using http our https requests btw?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro https

Comment: What do you mean by - token is in header but not in Authorization header?

Comment: @shanranm When I call $headers = apache_request_headers(); the token is in there but not in $headers['Authorization'] where I'm looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by downloading Flurl and Flurl.Http plugins and added this line:

```
 var result = await url.WithOAuthBearerToken(token).PostJsonAsync(jsonstring);
```

Credit: [Xamarin forms not sending Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468173/xamarin-forms-not-sending-authorization-header)

Also

[Fluent HTTP](https://flurl.dev/docs/fluent-http/)

Comment: This is just a workaround for the problem, bringing in a whole package (that is unnecessary in the first place) just for "solving" it is not a solution. Please try to debug why it is occurring. Is it, for you too, redirecting with a trailing slash? if so can you add trailing slash in the request url and try?

Comment: @shanranm I've tried with the trailing slash and the problem persists.